# Is there a way to extract all the features from Instagram users without using the API Graph?

Tags: python-3.x, instagram-api, feature-extraction, instagram-graph-api, instaloader

I'm colaborating in a project, and one of the tasks that we need to do is extracting features from Instagram users.
I've having some problems doing that but the responsible of the problem doesn't help me at all.

My teammate is using API Graph, and i've been using API's from python like Instaloader but i can't extract all of them and i tried to log me too. Also i used Instagrammy but now it doesn't work and was the same case.
I asked in a facebook group and they told me that the best way is API Graph.

I started the process to use API Graph but the responsible of that part is my teammate.
I want to extract all the features from Instagram using python if it's possible and i want to know if there's a way using other programming languages or there´s another tools for doing that.
I know that there are others API's but you need to pay for it and that's not the idea in this case.